# How to generate the rows number as order in a way that skip with the existing order using mysql script

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a table as below

```
+======+===========+=======+==========+
| team |    person | order | createdAt|
+======+===========+=======+==========+
|   A  |      John |       |2019/01/01|
+------+-----------+=======+==========+
|   B  |     Smith |       |2019/01/01|
+------+-----------+=======+==========+
|   A  |    Walter | 2     |2019/01/03|
+------+-----------+=======+==========+
|   A  |     Louis |       |2019/01/04|
+------+-----------+=======+==========+
|   C  | Elizabeth |       |2019/01/02|
+------+-----------+=======+==========+
|   B  |     Wayne |       |2019/01/02|
+------+-----------+=======+==========+
```

I want to set the order using sql based on following rules

1. order based on the team
2. order by the createdAt
3. the order should not be duplicate within the team. For example, if we noticed an order 2 had existed for team A already, we should use next available number 3 to fill in as order. It worth to point out that there can be multiple order existed already with in the same team. For example, for team A, if we only think of order by createdAt it should be John - 1, Louis - 2, Walter - 3. However, because Walter had been filled with 2, Louis can only be assigned 3.

For above example, what I expected is

```
    +======+===========+=======+==========+
    | team |    person | order | createdAt|
    +======+===========+=======+==========+
    |   A  |      John | 1     |2019/01/01|
    +------+-----------+=======+==========+
    |   B  |     Smith | 1     |2019/01/01|
    +------+-----------+=======+==========+
    |   A  |    Walter | 2     |2019/01/03|
    +------+-----------+=======+==========+
    |   A  |     Louis | 3     |2019/01/02|
    +------+-----------+=======+==========+
    |   C  | Elizabeth | 1     |2019/01/02|
    +------+-----------+=======+==========+
    |   B  |     Wayne | 2     |2019/01/02|
    +------+-----------+=======+==========+
```

I saw a lot of scripts to sort and create row_number to do it, but they cannot handle the case that pre-existing order not changing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(ordering,
                (seqnum +
                 sum( case when max_ordering <= seqnum then 1 else 0 end ) over (partition by team order by coalesce(ordering, seqnum))
                )
               ) as new_order
from (select t.*, max(ordering) over (partition by team order by coalesce(ordering, seqnum)) as max_ordering
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when ordering is null
                         then row_number() over (partition by team, ordering is null order by createdat)
                    end) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f94c626d7bd504be9cb77ec8ccb2f11) is a db<>fiddle.

Here is the idea:

- Enumerate the non-ordered rows with their new ordering -- this is called `seqnum`.
- Now you have two lists, with overlaps.  Count the number of existing `order` values up to each `seqnum` value.  This is tricky.  The idea is to count the number of `orders` with values up to and including the seqnum on each row.
- Then the final ordering is either `seqnum` plus the value calculated in the previous bullet, or the original `order`.